# Import wsdl file/artifacts to netbeans for SOAP beginner/test client with @webservice

Tags: java, netbeans

So I have been able to generate/publish the @webservice test class, view the WSDL in the browser, and then import it through the command prompt to my computers file system, but when I try to use the method to connect a client to it, I get "cannot find symbol" in netbeans. Do I have to somehow import these files specifically to netbeans? If so how?

Also, I was a little unsure of how to know what method to call by looking in the artifact files but I am pretty sure I am calling the right one. This is on page 447 of "Java Cookbook" by Ian Darwin. Any help is appreciated!
Best Regards,
Evan[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally the you'd generate a client stub based on the wsdl file. So you cannot just try to get a port on your class. You

- Need to generate a client stub based on that wsdl
- Get your port manually via JaxWS APIs

Comment: I used the JavaWS commands in the terminal: 'mkdir javawsclient", then,  "wsimport -d jaxwsclient - keep 'http://localhost:9090/calc?wsdl'". This created the files in the directory on my system. The book shows a file called "CalcService.java" my directory shows "JavaApplication15Service.class", because my class is JavaApplication15. When I try to use this to start the client in a new class in the same package as the web service "JavaApplication15 client = new JavaApplication15Service().getJavaApplication15Port();" it says "cannot find symbol".

Comment: You need to ensure that the source wsimport generated are put into your project or that the generated class files are part of your classpath. In additiona you most likely need to call `JavaApplication15Service` instead of `JavaApplication15`.

Comment: So, I have turned the directory into a jar and added to classpath, it is now recognized in the applications. However, when I run the server, then make a new application and try to connect, it says "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: jaxwsclient.service.toy.JavaApplication15".